# How to do bitwise shifting for signed (negative) integers?

Tags: r, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, 32-bit

In c-syntax, we can shift signed integers (negatives):  We can use ">>>" if we want to force and unsigned integer shift.

```
y = -1732584194
(y>>16)

-26438

x = 1732584193
(x>>16)

26437
```

Using R, there are bitwise operators https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/bitwise.html

`?bitwShiftL` for example shows the same page.  It states: "Shifting is done assuming the values represent unsigned integers."

```
y = -1732584194
bitwShiftR(y,16)  
# [1] 39098     ## wanted -26438


x = 1732584193
bitwShiftR(x,16)
# [1] 26437    ## works as expected
```

Show how do I perform a signed shift using R statistical programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own function to do this:

```r
Rshift <- function(val, nbits) floor(val/2^nbits)
```

Which gives:

```r
y = -1732584194
Rshift(y, 16)
#> [1] -26438

y = 1732584194
Rshift(y, 16)
#> [1] 26437
```

Or if you are used to coding in C, write a function in C and compile it as an R function using Rcpp:

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction("long long RShift(long long a, int b) { return a >> b;}")

y = -1732584194
RShift(y, 16)
#> [1] -26438

y = 1732584194
RShift(y, 16)
#> [1] 26437
```

Comment: Do you know how to add this Rcpp syntax to an R library that I host on github and build with Rstudio?

Answer (score 4):

Shift the opposite:

```
> y = -1732584194
> -bitwShiftR(-y,16) - 1
[1] -26438
```